# the trajectory of points whose powers of point to two circles have constant ratio

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Let $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ be circles with respective centers
$O_1$ and $O_2$ and respective radii $r_1$ and $r_2$,
and let $k$ be a real number
not equal to 1. Prove that the set of points $P$ such that
$$
PO_1^2 - r_1^2 = k(PO_2^2 - r_2^2)
$$
is a circle.

We know that when $r_1=0,r_2=0$, the problem reduces to the definition of 
[Apollonius' circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius). But how to show the same fact for such a case with pure geometry method ?